# How to split a rasterBrick into multiple rasterStacks

Tags: r, split, stack, raster

I have a rasterBrick that contains data stored in 181 layers.

```
> sstd
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 421, 649, 273229, 181  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent     : -150.0417, -39.95833, -10.041667, 40.04167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : xyz_SST2017.nc 
names      : X2017.02.01.12.00.00, X2017.02.02.12.00.00, X2017.02.03.12.00.00, X2017.02.04.12.00.00, X2017.02.05.12.00.00, X2017.02.06.12.00.00, X2017.02.07.12.00.00, X2017.02.08.12.00.00, X2017.02.09.12.00.00, X2017.02.10.12.00.00, X2017.02.11.12.00.00, X2017.02.12.12.00.00, X2017.02.13.12.00.00, X2017.02.14.12.00.00, X2017.02.15.12.00.00, ... 
Date/time  : 2017-02-01 12:00:00, 2017-07-31 12:00:00 (min, max)
varname    : tto 
level      :
```

1. I firstly wish the divide the Brick into multiple rasterStacks each containing 7 layers (with the exception of the final stack which will only have 5 layers).
2. I then would like to calculate the mean values for each of the new rasterStack objects, before storing the mean values as a new layer in a MASTER output rasterStack.

If I was using a dataframe, step 1 would be a simple case of using something like the `split()` function below to split up the input rasterBrick into the 26 blocks. However, I have been unable to find a way to do this when working with bricks.

```
block <- 7
n <- nlayers(sstd)
r  <- rep(1:ceiling(n/block),each=block)[1:n]
d <- split(sstd,r)
```

I have messed around with functions like `raster::subset`, and `SpaDES::splitRaster`, but these only seem to work to split individual rasters into tiles.

Below is the beginning of my attempt to map out what I want to do:

```
outstk = stack() #create an empty rasterStack to store results

for(i in seq(1,181,by=7)){
  stk = sstd[[i:i+7]] #this is wrong but I can’t figure out how to get it to work
  meanstk = calc(stk,mean,na.rm=TRUE) #calculate the mean for all layers in the new stack
  outstk = stack(outstk,meanstk) #add mean values to the output rasterstack as a new layer
}
```

I have a very basic understanding of R, but am not advanced and am not used to using bricks, so any help would be greatly appreciated as I am hitting a wall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stackApply for that

```
library(raster)
sstd <- brick(ncol=10, nrow=10, nl=181)
values(sstd) <- 1:18100

block <- 7
n <- nlayers(sstd)
r  <- rep(1:ceiling(n/block),each=block)[1:n]

m <- stackApply(sstd, r, mean)
```

And here is a rewrite of your loop

```
out <- list() 
start <- seq(1,181,by=7)
end <- pmin(nlayers(sstd), start + 7)

for(i in 1:length(start)){
  stk = sstd[[ start[i] : end[i] ]] 
  out[[i]] = mean(stk, na.rm=TRUE) 
}
out = stack(out)
```

The mistake you made was that instead of `i:i+7` you should say `i:(i+7)` because the `:` has preference.